# Removing unused imports in AngularJS project in bulk using Visual Studio Code

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm tasked with cleaning our AngularJS project to remove unused imports and variables. I use VS Code and through [TypeScript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero#overview) extension I can do what I want to do one file at a time. However, is there a way to fix all typescript files in project?

Comment: Maybe you can try `tslint` with the rule `no-unused-variable` and use the `tslint --fix`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For visual studio code, you can simply open your **preference settings** and add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

You can also enable/disable on save **per language** using following `setting.json`:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
},
```

This new feature has been released since [April](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23) last year in 2018. Hopefully this can be helpful!